# Authentication for SVN Server

Tags: svn, version-control, version, versioning

I installed Subversion on my server, and have added these lines to /conf/svnserve.conf in the repo that I have just created:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

In the passwd file I have added:

```
user = pass
```

However when I go to browse the repo with Tortoise SVN it does not accept my username and password, is there something I am missing? I am using this for the repo url:

```
svn+ssh://user@1.1.1.1/path/to/repo/trunk
```

Comment: What OS are you using?  If it is windows, then the problem maybe that you do not have a ssh application installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What server are you on? Windows or Unix? What client are you on? Windows or Unix?

As others have pointed out, Windows doesn't come with SSH, so you'll have to install it.

By the way, if you're using `svn+ssh`, you're suppose to use `sshd`'s authorization scheme, and not svnserve's authorization scheme. See the Subversion manual section on [Tunneling over SSH](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth).

I've setup ssh+svn access several times. If I remember correctly, you set your `svnserver.conf` to allow for anon read-write access because your users aren't going to log into Subversion via the `svnserve` process. They get access to the Subversion repository via the their account in the /etc/passwd file (or whatever a Windows sshd process would use).

Setting up `svn+ssh` is very tricky, and probably the hardest way to setup Subversion. On a typical Unix server, you make sure that the users don't have shell access. Otherwise, they have direct access to the raw repository files and can even delete them. The trick is that all of these users are in the same Unix group, and that the files in the subversion repository have read/write access to this group. You have to make sure `umask` is set to `006` and that the files in the repository are set to `770`/`660`.

I usually recommend using Apache httpd, and then using SSL certificates if you have to encrypt the network traffic. Then, you can use LDAP authentication which can talk to YP servers and Window Domain servers. You get the encryption handling of ssh, and the ability to foist Subversion security onto a well established process.

Comment: Unix server, Windows client. Thanks for the information I am looking into it.

Comment: I have been trying to research setting up an authenticated SVN server, could you perhaps help me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Windows doesn't come with a SSH application installed.  You will have to install an SSH app (like PuTTY) and set Tortoise SVN to use it.

I found the following blog entry which explains how to do it:

http://www.vectorns.com/blog/11-tortoisesvn-over-ssh-on-windows-via-putty